# date picker not supporting in django template table column

Tags: django, datepicker

date picker for form field , placed in an template was not supporting.. Here's the code

forms.py:

```
class GuestFacultyCourseOfferForm(BaseGuestFacultyCourseOfferForm):

        teaching_mode = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=TeachingMode.objects.all())
        location_mode = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=LocationMode.objects.all())
        # class_start_date = forms.DateField(required=True,)
        classstartdate = forms.DateField(label='Date',required=True)
```

template code:
 This is the script code for date picker which was given for form field "classstartdate".

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% url 'admin:jsi18n' %}"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css"> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'admin/js/jquery-new.js' %}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'admin/js/jquery-ui.min.js' %}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'admin/js/jquery-validate.js' %}"></script>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $( "#id_classstartdate" ).datepicker({
      changeMonth: true,
      changeYear: true,
      minDate:0,
      buttonImage: "{% static "admin/img/icon_calendar.gif" %}",
      buttonImageOnly: true,
      buttonText: "Select date",      
      showOn:"both",

    });
  });
  </script>
```

--> this is body code where i have given form fields in table:

```
<form  method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
<table id="formset" class="form">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>TEACHING MODE</th>
      <th>LOCATION MODE</th>
      <th>CLASS START DATE</th>

    </tr>
  </thead>
{% for form in formset_assign_faculty.forms %}
  <tr class="{% cycle row1,row2 %}">
        <td>{{ form.teaching_mode}} {{ form.teaching_mode.errors.as_ul }}</td>
    <td>{{ form.location_mode}} {{ form.location_mode.errors.as_ul }}</td>
    <td>{{ form.classstartdate}} {{ form.location_mode.errors.as_ul }}</td>

  </tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>

</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using formset the input id of each form is different, it is formed like "id_" + form prefix + field name.

So, try to change `$("#id_classstartdate")` where you initiate datepicker to `$("[id^=id_][id$=classstartdate]")`. This will find inputs which start with "id_" and end with form field name `classtartdate`.

Comment: Thank You..but i dnt knw the pblm where that was exactly raising, even i done like u said , the datefield was coming as text Box